# What is the function "defs" in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, cl, maclisp

In the "Dictio" file, located at the link "Text-only console version" of [this site](http://www.semaphorecorp.com/misc/shrdlu.html), I've noticed a Lisp command (?) called `defs`.

I assume that this is something similar to `defun`, but am unable to find any information on what `defs` does; is it used to define a function, or maybe a variable? I am looking to reproduce this code using modern techniques and it would help to know the purpose of `defs`.

The `defs` calls seem to also include more than a name before the arguments (I would expect it to read (`defs name () body`).

Looking at the first function in the list, there appears to be more included in this "function definition" [the word 'features' specifically] and in the third function, there is `['semantics']` included after what appears to be the name of the function (before the arguments).

Comment: It is defined in the file SYSCOM.

Comment: I was wondering why someone would mark this question as "not researched" ... I looked, but not hard enough apparently.  Thank you Rainer.

Answer (score 2):

`DEFS` is defined by the software in the file `SYSCOM`.

It is a *FEXPR*, which is a function which gets the arguments unevaluated. Common Lisp has no such feature. It uses macros instead.

Example use:

```
(DEFS \#COLOR 
    FEXPR (LAMBDA (A)
            (EVAL (SUBST (CAR A)
                         'COLOR
                         '(OBJECT 
                           (MARKERS\: (\#PHYSOB COLOR) 
                                      PROCEDURE\: ((\#COLOR *** COLOR))))))) 
    PRIORITY 192. 
    SYS (\#PROPERTY))
```

Here you have a symbol `#COLOR`. It gets a function (actually a *FEXPR*) defined under this name. Also it puts a `PRIORITY` and `SYS` onto the property list of the symbol. Thus `DEFS` is used to define symbols with functions and properties in one defining form.